# Is it possible to set the ListView selected item background color? Right now on Windows 8.1 its Blue and I want it to be transparent if possible

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Windows 8.1 app using C# and XAML. I have a List View and I want to change the default High Light color of an selected item. I was seeing many code examples and Custom Render , I was trying to implement those but they do not work for me.

In general I'm having troubles modifying the default themes of controls because I don't find useful documentation. It would be great if someone can help me with the highlight color and also recommend me good documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8.1 project's `App.xaml` class:

- Create App Resources & override `ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush` style

  < Application.Resources>

  ```
  < ResourceDictionary>

      < SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent"/>

  < /ResourceDictionary>
  ```

  < /Application.Resources>

Comment: not needed actually,  this works fine(for all Listviews)

Comment: OK can change Mouse Hover color Using ResourceDictionary

Comment: You can find all WinRT template styles from here: https://gist.github.com/longzheng/2308859